# Object destructuring won't take numbers?

Tags: javascript, object, destructuring

```js
    let pokeApi = ()=>{
      let randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 898);
      let url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${randomize}`
      fetch(url)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data)
          let {height, weight, stats:{0: {base_stat}} } = data;
        })
    }

   pokeApi();
```

stats is defined as an array with 6 objects. I'm trying to call line 0, and inside of 0 the name, but whenever I type a number it gives me an error I can't fix unless I delete the number.

How can I destructure so it equals this...   data.stats[0]["base_stat"]

Comment: Arrays are `[...]` not `{...}` which are objects. Post an example of JSON

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Object keys must _not_ start with a number `stats:{0: {base_stat}}` is an invalid object

Answer (score 1):

To get the first element of array with the help of destructure, you can do like,

`stats:[ {base_stat: firstBaseStat} ]`

So the final destructuring will be like,

```
let {height, weight, stats:[ {base_stat: firstBaseStat} ] } = data;
```

And you can make use of `firstBaseStat` to get the first value.

**Working Example:**

```js
let pokeApi = ()=>{
  let randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 898);
  let url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${randomize}`
  fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      let {height, weight, stats:[ {base_stat: firstBaseStat} ] } = data;
      console.log('height ', height, 'weight ', weight, 'first stats ', firstBaseStat)
    })
}

pokeApi();
```